# Reading a non-standard text file in Python

Tags: python, file, text

I am trying to read a file with following table. But currently when I try to do it my way, it sees all the values as strings, and I need the values as integers, floats, and lists.

```
0  1  [5]    [1,3]  1  -1    0    [5]
1  1  [4,5]  [0,2]  2  -1    3    [2]
2  1  [4]    [1,3]  2  0     3    [1]
3  1  []     [0,2]  1  0     0    []
4  0  []     [1,2]  3  -0.5  4.5  []
5  0  []     [0,1]  3  -1.5  1.5  [0]
```

This is my code:

```
regions =[]
with open('country.txt', 'r') as fh:
    data = fh.readlines()
for i in data[1:-1]:
    row = []
    for s in i.split():
        row.append(s)
    regions.append(row)
print(regions)
```

Comment: You can iterate over the file lines directly eh, no need for `readlines()` and then another loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row.append(ast.literal_eval(s))` or `row.append(json.loads(s))` as a simple way to parse numbers and lists.

Answer (score 1):

Python is a dynamically typed language. So these won't automatically throw errors even if you misread them into strings.

In order to read in a string as an integer, you can cast it as follows:

```
num = int("1")
```

I would split the row as you did, and then knowing the type of each column, use a [regex matcher](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to read them into the desired type.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about `regex`? If not, it's a great time to read about it.
Try like below:

```
import re
matcher = re.search(r'(\d)\s+(\d)\s+\[(\d*),*(\d*)')
num1 = int(matcher.group(1))
num2 = int(matcher.group(2))
```

And so on